# run mariadb (mysql) on multiple cpu core

Tags: mysql, mariadb, connections

How can I make MariaDB on Debian 11 use all cores equally?

Currently, my configuration is using version 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1-log on a server with

- 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K 24 core CPU
- 128GB RAM
- and 1TB NVMe.

My current MySQL configuration file looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
bind-address   = 0.0.0.0
innodb_read_io_threads = 16
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_purge_threads = 4
innodb_page_cleaners = 4
innodb_log_write_ahead_size=4
thread_cache_size = 64
thread_handling = pool-of-threads
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100G
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
key_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
innodb_lru_scan_depth = 4096
innodb_change_buffer_max_size = 50
innodb_adaptive_hash_index = 0
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_flush_sync = 0
innodb_max_undo_log_size = 2G
innodb_undo_logs = 128
innodb_use_native_aio = 0
innodb_undo_log_truncate = ON
innodb_undo_directory = /var/lib/mysql/undo/
max_connections = 2000
max_allowed_packet = 256M
wait_timeout = 600
interactive_timeout = 600
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time = 5
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 1
log_slow_admin_statements = 1
log_slow_slave_statements = 1
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

My MariaDB server is handling high HTTP traffic with nginx, but the problem is that it's only using some CPU and not utilizing the other cores as  24 multi-core workers.

When I check the htop screen, it shows that MariaDB is using more than 100% of one CPU.
[image]

the output of the following query:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

*`Threads_connected 938`*

How can I configure MariaDB to use all cores equally?

Comment: `innodb_thread_concurrency` is deprecated and ignore from MariaDB version 10.5.5 and later.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` is deprecated and ignore since 10.5.1.

Comment: `Threads_running` is more interesting than `Threads_connected`.  Check it several times (it is likely to be bouncing around).

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer** -- MariaDB and MySQL essentially never run out of cores.

**Long Answer**

`htop` is not precise enough.  Do `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` -- The connections that say "Sleep" are not using any CPU cores.  The connections that are "running" some SQL may be using a core, or they may be waiting for something.

I don't think MariaDB has any case where multiple cores are employed to help in one connection.  (MySQL has very few simple queries that make use of multiple cores.  But even they may be I/O-bound.)

InnoDB has a small number of global helper threads, but these are mostly I/O-bound, so they rarely take any cores.

Meanwhile, it is up to the OS to decide which process gets which core.  Ubuntu seems to assign cores randomly.  Continue to watch your Debian; see if it does likewise.

And nothing struck me as misconfigured in the configuration.  However, you might want to lower `long_query_time` to pick up on more naughty queries.

> running more than 1000 queries in parallel

MySQL/MariaDB tries to run the queries fast so they don't stumble over each other.  The works OK for a few dozen active queries, but after that a variety of problems make it difficult to get more done.  The common suspects are I/O, transactional locks, memory allocation, and various shared caches.

Running lots of queries *simultaneously* is not a practical goal.  *Finishing* lots of queries *per minute* is a reasonable goal.

Comment: what about using MySQL replication, it this will help to decrease the load on my server ? and what is the best replication type that I can use ?

Comment: Before talking about replication, let's see if we can cut back on CPU utilization by improving the queries.  Use the [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) to find the long-running queries

Comment: I have a lot of slow query because the server overload, all my table are indexed

Comment: Single-column indexes?  Or composite?  Any non-sargeable expressions?  How about sometimes-slow formulations like 'IN ( SELECT ...)`?  `JOINs` with inconsistent datatypes?

Comment: I'm using a single-column index with the default index type BTREE. My queries execute quickly when running them individually, but when running more than 1000 queries in parallel, the performance becomes slower. Additionally, when checking the status using the command "SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name = 'Threads_connected';," I noticed that the number of connected threads is limited to 2877. However, I have set the max_connections to 3500.

Comment: I added more.  Don't try to do too many queries _simultaneously_.  See how many you can do _per minute_.  If you want to use more cores, then maybe you need a more complex query.

Answer (score 1):

You processor Intel i9-12900K aka Alder Lake, has a unique non-symmetrical architecture.
It says you have 24 cores, but that's 8 non-hyperthreaded cores, and 8 hyperthreaded ones. OS scheduler could be confused a bit, scheduling on such thing. I have one of those myself, and I disabled hyperthreading, so I see 16 cores, instead of 24, but it behaves less erratic since.

Unrelated to this, one of the things you can try is to increase thread_pool_size (to 32, 48, maybe  a little more) and see if it behaves better. Default setting is number of processors, which in ideal should load all of cores, but threadpool is not informed about every possible situation where threads wait, to it can overestimate the load.

Comment: Also, threads_connected has no relation to the actual load. they can be  connected and idle. You better look at "show variables like 'thread%', which will spit  more relevant information for threadpool. there are also some information schema tables : information_schema.thread_pool_groups,   information_schema.thread_pool_queues,  information_schema.thread_pool_stats, information_schema.thread_pool_waits. you can select * from any of them, but it might be not trivial to understand. There is also the information_schema.processlist. Maybe you just don't have that many active connections .

Comment: Please simply provide all of `SHOW VARIABLES;` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`